# image with same width and css style, but doesn't look the same on different browsers

Tags: html, css

I worked on a URL shortener website, and I used also some `wow.js` and `animate.css` libraries and I was surprised when I finished the work when I saw the hero image of the first section with the same CSS style `width: 50%`.

Well, it looks like I want it on Microsoft Edge but it looks different on Fire Fox, the only solution I found to make the image looks like Microsoft Edge is to change the to `width: 100%`

live demo: https://urlshortapi.netlify.app/public/

My code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    /* ### Primary */
    --Cyan: hsl(180, 66%, 49%);
    --Dark-Violet: hsl(257, 27%, 26%);
    --Black: #000;
    --White: #FFF;

    /* ### Secondary */
    --Red: hsl(0, 87%, 67%);
    --Green: green;

    /* ### Neutral */
    --Gray: hsl(0, 0%, 75%);
    --Grayish-Violet: hsl(257, 7%, 63%);
    --Very-Dark-Blue: hsl(255, 11%, 22%);
    --Very-Dark-Violet: hsl(260, 8%, 14%);
}

body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
}

nav>div {
    margin: 18px 20px;
}

.left-side {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

ul>li {
    margin: 0 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: var(--Gray);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}

ul>li:hover {
    color: var(--Very-Dark-Blue);
}

.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}

.right-side {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--Gray);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 12px;
    transition: 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
    color: var(--Very-Dark-Blue);
}

header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 130px;
    width: 100%;
}

.title {
    font-size: 4.5vw;
    line-height: 5vw;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.pre-title {
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    width: 90%;
    color: var(--Gray);
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.header-side {
    margin-left: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}

.illustration {
    width: 50%;
}

.exc {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: var(--Cyan);
    transition: 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.exc:hover {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    color: var(--Very-Dark-Blue);
}

.started-btn {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: transparent;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--Gray);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.line {
    display: none;
}

.input-div {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-image: url(../images/bg-boost-desktop.svg);
    background-color: var(--Very-Dark-Blue);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.input {
    padding: 10px 12px;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: transparent;
    transition: 2s;
}

.alert-div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 70%;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}

.alert-i {
    color: var(--Red);
    transition: 0.1s;
}

/*for js style*/
.input-check-red {
    border: 2px solid var(--Red);
    padding: 8px 12px;
}

.input-check-red::placeholder {
    color: var(--Red)
}

.input-check-green {
    border: 2px solid var(--Green);
    padding: 8px 12px;
}

.input-btn {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: transparent;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: 1s;
}

/*js style for each copy btn*/
.copy-btn-style,
.copy-btn-style:hover {
    background-color: var(--Very-Dark-Blue);
    color: var(--White);
}

.added {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.added>p {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: var(--Black);
}

.added>div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.added>div>a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: var(--Cyan);
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.copy-btn {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.advanced-stats-main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.title2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.8vw;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.hamburger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.hamburger:hover {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
}

.pre-title2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: var(--Grayish-Violet);
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 80%;
    line-height: 2vw;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.feautures {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 80%;
}

.feature {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.separate {
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    top: -35px;
    background-color: var(--Cyan);
}

.adittion::after {
    content: "";
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--Very-Dark-Violet);
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 55%;
}

.f1::after {
    background-image: url(../images/icon-brand-recognition.svg);
}

.f2::after {
    background-image: url(../images/icon-detailed-records.svg);
}

.f3::after {
    background-image: url(../images/icon-fully-customizable.svg);
}

.f1 {
    top: -70px;
}

.f2 {
    top: -35px;
}

.f3 {
    top: 0px;
}

.title3 {
    color: var(--Black);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
}

.pre-title3 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: var(--Grayish-Violet);
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 2vw;
}

.boost-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3vw;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.boost {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--Very-Dark-Blue);
    background-image: url(../images/bg-boost-desktop.svg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 180px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.boost-btn {
    padding: 8px 30px;
}

footer {
    background-color: var(--Very-Dark-Violet);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

footer h2 {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

footer a {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    min-width: 30px;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: var(--Cyan);
}

.wrapper-parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(2),
.wrapper>div:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.wrapper>div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sm {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.sm>* {
    margin: 0 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sm>* path {
    transition: 1s;
}

.sm>* path:hover {
    fill: var(--Cyan);
}

.rights {
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:850px) {
    header {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    .illustration {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .title {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.1rem;
        line-height: 2.4rem;
    }

    .added>p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .pre-title {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        line-height: 1.3rem;
    }

    header>* {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo:hover {
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: flex;
    }

    .header-side {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .started-btn {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .line {
        display: flex;
        height: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: var(--Gray);
    }

    .desk-ul>*,
    .right-side>* {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }

    .desk-ul>*:hover {
        color: var(--Cyan);
    }

    .login:hover {
        color: var(--Cyan);
    }

    .desk-ul,
    .right-side {
        flex-direction: column;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: var(--Black);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 90%;
        padding: 20px 40px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: 2s;
    }

    .sign-btn {
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .desk-ul {
        top: -500px;
    }

    .right-side {
        top: -500px;
    }

    .desk-ul-style {
        /*for js style*/
        top: 230px;
    }

    .right-side-style {
        top: 450px;
    }

    .pre-title {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .feautures {
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .title2 {
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }

    .pre-title2 {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        line-height: 1.4rem;
    }

    .separate {
        height: 40px;
        width: 10px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }

    .title3 {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }

    .pre-title3 {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        line-height: normal;
    }

    .f1,
    .f2,
    .f3 {
        top: 0;
        width: 80%;
    }

    .boost-title {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .boost-btn,
    .started-btn {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    footer {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .footer-logo {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .wrapper {
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .wrapper-parent {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .wrapper>div:nth-child(2),
    .wrapper>div:nth-child(3) {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .wrapper>div {
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    }

    footer h2 {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

    footer a {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    .sm {
        margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    }

    .rights {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        top: 30px;
        left: 0;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    .input-div {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .shorten-btn {
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .title2 {
        line-height: 2.2rem;
    }

    .pre-title2 {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .alert-div {
        width: 100%;
        top: 5px;
    }

    .boost-btn {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .title3 {
        line-height: 2rem;
    }

    .input {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .added {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .added>div {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .feature {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../WOW-master/css/libs/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Shortly URL shortening API Challenge</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!---------------------- nav start ---------------------->
    <nav class="wow fadeIn">
        <div class="left-side">
            <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="#" class="logo">
            <ul class="desk-ul">
                <li>Feautures</li>
                <li>Pricing</li>
                <li>Resources</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <a href="#" class="login">Login</a>
            <a href="#" class="exc sign-btn">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
        <img class="hamburger" src="images/bars-solid.svg" alt="#">
    </nav>
    <!---------------------- nav end ---------------------->
    <!---------------------- header start ---------------------->
    <header>
        <div class="header-side">
            <h1 class="title wow bounceInUp">More than just shorter links</h1>
            <p class="pre-title wow wobble">Build your brand’s recognition and get detailed insights on how your links
                are
                performing.</p>
            <button class="started-btn exc wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s">Get Started</button>
        </div>
        <img class="illustration wow flipInX" src="images/illustration-working.svg" alt="#">
    </header>
    <!---------------------- header end ---------------------->
    <!---------------------- section start ---------------------->
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="input-div wow fadeIn">
                <div class="alert-div">
                    <input type="url" placeholder="Shorten a link here ..." class="input">
                    <i class="alert-i">Please add a link</i>
                </div>
                <button class="exc input-btn shorten-btn">Shorten It!</button>
            </div>
            <div class="added added-template wow bounce">
                <p>see your website link</p>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">https://shrtco.de/??????</a>
                    <button class="exc copy-btn input-btn">Copy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="advanced-stats-main">
            <h2 class="title2 wow bounceInLeft">Advanced Statistics</h2>
            <p class="pre-title2 wow fadeInRight">Track how your links are performing across the
                web with our advanced statistics
                dashboard</p>
        </div>
        <div class="feautures">
            <div class="feature adittion f1 wow flipInX">
                <h3 class="title3">Brand Recognition</h3>
                <p class="pre-title3">Boost your brand recognition with each click. Generic links don’t mean a thing.
                    Branded links help instil confidence in your content.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="separate wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s"></div>
            <div class="feature adittion f2 wow flipInY">
                <h3 class="title3">Detailed Records</h3>
                <p class="pre-title3">Gain insights into who is clicking your links. Knowing when and where people
                    engage with your content helps inform better decisions.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="separate wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s"></div>
            <div class="feature adittion f3 wow flipInX">
                <h3 class="title3">Fully Customizable</h3>
                <p class="pre-title3">Improve brand awareness and content discoverability through customizable links,
                    supercharging audience engagement.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="boost">
            <h2 class="title2 boost-title wow bounceInUp">Boost your links today</h2>
            <button class="exc started-btn boost-btn wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s">Get Started</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!---------------------- section end ---------------------->
    <!---------------------- footer start ---------------------->
    <footer class="wow fadeIn">
        <div class="wrapper-parent">
            <svg class="footer-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="121" height="33">
                <path fill="#FFFFFF"
                    d="M16.715 7.932c-.068-.09-.306-.26-.714-.51s-.918-.51-1.53-.782-1.281-.51-2.006-.714a8.005 8.005 0 00-2.176-.306c-1.995 0-2.992.669-2.992 2.006 0 .408.107.748.323 1.02.215.272.532.516.952.731.419.215.946.414 1.58.595l1.406.393.805.219c1.156.317 2.198.663 3.128 1.037.929.374 1.717.839 2.363 1.394a5.647 5.647 0 011.496 2.023c.35.793.527 1.745.527 2.856 0 1.36-.255 2.51-.765 3.451-.51.94-1.185 1.7-2.023 2.278-.84.578-1.802.997-2.89 1.258-1.088.26-2.21.391-3.366.391a19.68 19.68 0 01-5.44-.799c-.884-.26-1.74-.572-2.567-.935A14.358 14.358 0 01.53 22.28l2.448-4.862c.09.113.385.329.884.646.498.317 1.116.635 1.853.952.736.317 1.558.6 2.465.85.906.25 1.824.374 2.754.374 1.972 0 2.958-.6 2.958-1.802 0-.453-.148-.827-.442-1.122-.295-.295-.703-.561-1.224-.799a12.455 12.455 0 00-1.504-.56l-1.702-.495-.976-.288c-1.111-.34-2.074-.708-2.89-1.105-.816-.397-1.49-.856-2.023-1.377a5.003 5.003 0 01-1.19-1.802c-.261-.68-.391-1.473-.391-2.38 0-1.27.238-2.391.714-3.366a7.266 7.266 0 011.938-2.465 8.435 8.435 0 012.839-1.513c1.076-.34 2.215-.51 3.417-.51.838 0 1.666.08 2.482.238.816.159 1.598.363 2.346.612.748.25 1.445.533 2.09.85.647.317 1.242.635 1.786.952l-2.448 4.624zM40.139 25h-5.44V14.97c0-1.156-.227-2.006-.68-2.55-.454-.544-1.077-.816-1.87-.816-.318 0-.663.074-1.037.221a4.173 4.173 0 00-1.088.646 5.827 5.827 0 00-.97 1.003 4.4 4.4 0 00-.68 1.292V25h-5.44V.18h5.44v9.962a6.786 6.786 0 012.602-2.465c1.076-.578 2.26-.867 3.553-.867 1.201 0 2.17.21 2.907.629.736.42 1.303.952 1.7 1.598.396.646.663 1.371.799 2.176.136.805.204 1.592.204 2.363V25zm12.34.34c-1.519 0-2.873-.25-4.063-.748-1.19-.499-2.193-1.173-3.01-2.023a8.54 8.54 0 01-1.852-2.958 9.97 9.97 0 01-.63-3.519c0-1.224.21-2.397.63-3.519a8.54 8.54 0 011.853-2.958c.816-.85 1.819-1.53 3.009-2.04s2.544-.765 4.063-.765c1.519 0 2.867.255 4.046.765 1.179.51 2.176 1.19 2.992 2.04a8.754 8.754 0 011.87 2.958 9.736 9.736 0 01.646 3.519 9.97 9.97 0 01-.63 3.519 8.54 8.54 0 01-1.852 2.958c-.816.85-1.82 1.524-3.01 2.023-1.19.499-2.543.748-4.062.748zM48.5 16.092c0 1.405.374 2.533 1.122 3.383.748.85 1.7 1.275 2.856 1.275a3.59 3.59 0 001.564-.34c.476-.227.89-.544 1.24-.952a4.57 4.57 0 00.834-1.479 5.632 5.632 0 00.306-1.887c0-1.405-.374-2.533-1.122-3.383-.748-.85-1.689-1.275-2.822-1.275a3.702 3.702 0 00-2.84 1.292 4.57 4.57 0 00-.832 1.479 5.632 5.632 0 00-.306 1.887zm27.776-4.284c-1.315.023-2.505.238-3.57.646-1.065.408-1.836 1.02-2.312 1.836V25h-5.44V7.15h4.998v3.604c.612-1.201 1.4-2.142 2.363-2.822.963-.68 1.989-1.031 3.077-1.054h.544c.113 0 .227.011.34.034v4.896zm14.074 12.24a21.71 21.71 0 01-2.567.884c-.963.272-1.932.408-2.907.408-.68 0-1.32-.085-1.92-.255a4.286 4.286 0 01-1.582-.816c-.453-.374-.81-.867-1.07-1.479-.262-.612-.392-1.349-.392-2.21v-9.316h-2.278V7.15h2.278V1.472h5.44V7.15h3.638v4.114h-3.638v7.446c0 .59.147 1.014.442 1.275.295.26.669.391 1.122.391.408 0 .827-.068 1.258-.204.43-.136.805-.283 1.122-.442l1.054 4.318zM92.627.18h5.44v18.462c0 1.36.578 2.04 1.734 2.04.272 0 .572-.04.901-.119.329-.08.63-.198.901-.357l.714 4.08c-.68.317-1.462.567-2.346.748-.884.181-1.711.272-2.482.272-1.564 0-2.765-.408-3.604-1.224-.839-.816-1.258-1.995-1.258-3.536V.18zm11.456 27.506c.454.159.879.272 1.275.34a6.4 6.4 0 001.071.102c.658 0 1.168-.227 1.53-.68.363-.453.692-1.27.986-2.448l-6.8-17.85h5.61l4.148 13.192 3.57-13.192h5.1l-6.8 20.74a7.106 7.106 0 01-2.55 3.587c-1.224.918-2.674 1.377-4.352 1.377a8.17 8.17 0 01-1.377-.119 7.516 7.516 0 01-1.41-.391v-4.658z" />
            </svg>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div>
                    <h2>Feautures</h2> <a href="#">Link Shortening</a><a href="#">Branded Links</a><a
                        href="#">Analytics</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Resources</h2> <a href="#">Blog</a><a href="#">Developers</a><a href="#">Support Company</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Company</h2><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Our Team</a><a href="#">Careers</a><a
                        href="#">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sm">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
                    <path fill="#FFF"
                        d="M22.675 0H1.325C.593 0 0 .593 0 1.325v21.351C0 23.407.593 24 1.325 24H12.82v-9.294H9.692v-3.622h3.128V8.413c0-3.1 1.893-4.788 4.659-4.788 1.325 0 2.463.099 2.795.143v3.24l-1.918.001c-1.504 0-1.795.715-1.795 1.763v2.313h3.587l-.467 3.622h-3.12V24h6.116c.73 0 1.323-.593 1.323-1.325V1.325C24 .593 23.407 0 22.675 0z" />
                </svg>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="20">
                    <path fill="#FFF"
                        d="M24 2.557a9.83 9.83 0 01-2.828.775A4.932 4.932 0 0023.337.608a9.864 9.864 0 01-3.127 1.195A4.916 4.916 0 0016.616.248c-3.179 0-5.515 2.966-4.797 6.045A13.978 13.978 0 011.671 1.149a4.93 4.93 0 001.523 6.574 4.903 4.903 0 01-2.229-.616c-.054 2.281 1.581 4.415 3.949 4.89a4.935 4.935 0 01-2.224.084 4.928 4.928 0 004.6 3.419A9.9 9.9 0 010 17.54a13.94 13.94 0 007.548 2.212c9.142 0 14.307-7.721 13.995-14.646A10.025 10.025 0 0024 2.557z" />
                </svg>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
                    <path fill="#FFF"
                        d="M12 0C5.373 0 0 5.372 0 12c0 5.084 3.163 9.426 7.627 11.174-.105-.949-.2-2.405.042-3.441.218-.937 1.407-5.965 1.407-5.965s-.359-.719-.359-1.782c0-1.668.967-2.914 2.171-2.914 1.023 0 1.518.769 1.518 1.69 0 1.029-.655 2.568-.994 3.995-.283 1.194.599 2.169 1.777 2.169 2.133 0 3.772-2.249 3.772-5.495 0-2.873-2.064-4.882-5.012-4.882-3.414 0-5.418 2.561-5.418 5.207 0 1.031.397 2.138.893 2.738a.36.36 0 01.083.345l-.333 1.36c-.053.22-.174.267-.402.161-1.499-.698-2.436-2.889-2.436-4.649 0-3.785 2.75-7.262 7.929-7.262 4.163 0 7.398 2.967 7.398 6.931 0 4.136-2.607 7.464-6.227 7.464-1.216 0-2.359-.631-2.75-1.378l-.748 2.853c-.271 1.043-1.002 2.35-1.492 3.146C9.57 23.812 10.763 24 12 24c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12 0-6.628-5.373-12-12-12z" />
                </svg>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
                    <path fill="#FFF"
                        d="M12 2.163c3.204 0 3.584.012 4.85.07 3.252.148 4.771 1.691 4.919 4.919.058 1.265.069 1.645.069 4.849 0 3.205-.012 3.584-.069 4.849-.149 3.225-1.664 4.771-4.919 4.919-1.266.058-1.644.07-4.85.07-3.204 0-3.584-.012-4.849-.07-3.26-.149-4.771-1.699-4.919-4.92-.058-1.265-.07-1.644-.07-4.849 0-3.204.013-3.583.07-4.849.149-3.227 1.664-4.771 4.919-4.919 1.266-.057 1.645-.069 4.849-.069zM12 0C8.741 0 8.333.014 7.053.072 2.695.272.273 2.69.073 7.052.014 8.333 0 8.741 0 12c0 3.259.014 3.668.072 4.948.2 4.358 2.618 6.78 6.98 6.98C8.333 23.986 8.741 24 12 24c3.259 0 3.668-.014 4.948-.072 4.354-.2 6.782-2.618 6.979-6.98.059-1.28.073-1.689.073-4.948 0-3.259-.014-3.667-.072-4.947-.196-4.354-2.617-6.78-6.979-6.98C15.668.014 15.259 0 12 0zm0 5.838a6.162 6.162 0 100 12.324 6.162 6.162 0 000-12.324zM12 16a4 4 0 110-8 4 4 0 010 8zm6.406-11.845a1.44 1.44 0 100 2.881 1.44 1.44 0 000-2.881z" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="rights">&copy;Okba All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </footer>
    <!---------------------- footer end ---------------------->


    <script src="script/script.js"></script>
    <script src="../WOW-master/dist/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        new WOW().init();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[this is how it looks on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxyUz.png)

[this is how it looks on Edge and I want it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfnNL.png)

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, the first step that you will want to do is read and follow [mcve]

Comment: try adding in a `width: 50%;` to the `.header-side` div as well

Comment: Or add to the `.illustration` css `flex-shrink: 0;`

Comment: Or change the `width:50%;` to `flex-basis: 50%;`

Comment: Yep it is, the first solution is working, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank to Steve i found the answer, which is: to define a (width: 50%) to the left div that contains the title, paragraph and the button.